# Coldfusion string::split() issue

Tags: string, coldfusion, split

I have the following code

```
<cffunction name="getObjTag" returnType="string" output="false">
    <cfargument name="obj" Type="string" required="true">
    <cfargument name="tagname" Type="string" required="true">
    <cfreturn obj.split("<" & tagname.toUpperCase() & ">")[2]>
</cffunction>
```

Which results in the following error

```
Invalid CFML construct found on line 96 at column 63.

ColdFusion was looking at the following text:

[

The CFML compiler was processing:

A cfreturn tag beginning on line 96, column 10.
A cfreturn tag beginning on line 96, column 10.
```

Why is this? This happens on compile, not run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CF can't access the results of the split as an array directly from the function call. You need an intermediate variable.

```
<cfset var tmpArray = arrayNew(1)/>
<cfset tmpArray = arguments.obj.split("<" & arguments.tagname.toUpperCase() & ">")/>
<cfif arrayLen(tmpArray) gt 1>
   <cfreturn tmpArray[2]/>
<cfelse>
   <cfreturn ""/>
</cfif>
```

You also need to watch your indexes. Although the java array underneath is 0 index'ed, using coldfusion to get at it makes it indexed by 1.

Comment: Good answer, but see mine as well.  CF9 can handle this.

Answer (score 3):

CF 9 added the ability to access the results of the split as an array directly from the function call.  The following works as expected on my local install of 9.0.1:

```
<cfset foo = "this is a string" />
<cfdump var="#foo.split(" ")[1]#" />
```

The dump shows 'this' in this example.

Comment: can you post a link to some documentation on split().  I am having a hard time finding anything.  Thanks...

Comment: cfEngineers - it's a java method: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)